# Find the sum of a complicated telescoping series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think with this problem I am supposed to simplify the interior here or regroup but I am unsure of how to approach it:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(sin\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\pi }{2n+1}\right)-sin\left(\frac{n\pi }{2n-1}\right)\right)$$

This appears to be a telescoping series where the interior terms cancel but I'm not sure how to begin this the right way.  Do I start by trying to simplify the inside or trying to break it up into two separate sums? I just want to know where to start on this one.

Comment: Break into 2 sums, and re-index one of them.

Comment: You can get the right font and spacing for $\sin$ using `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andronicus almost but not quite answer re-done...
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{N }\:\left(\sin\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\pi }{2n+1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{n\pi }{2n-1}\right)\right)= 
\\
\sum _{n=1}^{N }\:\sin\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)\pi }{2n+1}\right)-\sum _{n=1}^{N }\:\sin\left(\frac{n\pi }{2n-1}\right) = 
\\
\sum _{n=2}^{N+1 }\:\sin\left(\frac{n\pi }{2n-1}\right)-\sum _{n=1}^{N }\:\sin\left(\frac{n\pi }{2n-1}\right)=
\\
\sin\left(\frac{(N+1)\pi }{2N+1}\right) -\sin{\pi}
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sin\left(\frac{(N+1)\pi }{2N+1}\right) -\sin{\pi}\right]
=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin \pi = 1 - 0 = 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could make it more obvious writind
$$a_n=\sin \left(\frac{n+1}{2 n+1}\pi\right)-\sin \left(\frac{  n}{2 n-1}\pi\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4 n+2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4 n-2}\right)$$ which is clearly telescoping. So
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2 (2 p+1)}\right)$$

For large values of $p$, using Taylor expansion
$$S_p=1-\frac{\pi ^2 }{32 }\frac{(p-1)}{ p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$

Try it for $p=10$. You have
$$S_{10}=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{42}\right)\approx 0.997204$$ while the above truncated expansion gives
$$S_{10}\sim 1-\frac{9 \pi ^2}{32000}\approx 0.997224$$